# bold math in section yields wrong navigation text

Tags: table-of-contents, navigation, section-titles, boldsymbol

I have the problem, that I want a **math-symbol** with text in the section name. The problem is, that `\boldsymbol` yields something really weird in the navigation bar on the left (namely something like `bold0mu mumu XnredXnredsectionXnred...`). Either I have this weird thing going on the navigation bar or it is not bold in the `ToC`. As `standalone` example:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{Something like $\boldsymbol{X_n^{\mathrm{red}}}$}
Lorem ipsum

\section[Or like $V_k^{\mathrm{blue}}$]{Or like $\boldsymbol{V_k^{\mathrm{blue}}}$}
dolor sit
\end{document}
```

Comment: Firstly `hyperref` should be loaded last (with a few exceptions). Secondly see your log, you'll see a lot of `Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (Unicode):
(hyperref)                removing `subscript' on input line 13.` meaning that this content cannot be converted into the hyperref bookmarks (or what they are called). You'll need to use something like `\texorpdfstring{For text}{For bookmarks}`.

Comment: Thus something similar to `\section{Something like \textorpdfstring{$\boldsymbol{X_n^{\mathrm{red}}}$}{Xnred}}` The bookmarks can only handle unicode so getting things to match is difficult.

Comment: Great! Thank you very much, this solves my problem. A little bit weird, that it added so much nonsense, but with the "\textorpdfstring" it works like a charm.

Comment: You may post this as an answer, so I can properly close this question.

Comment: I'll do that tomorrow, not at pc any more...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd want to use [`hyperref`](https://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref)'s macro

```latex
\texorpdfstring{output in PDF}{output in bookmarks}
```

You can also use unicode character in bookmarks if you add such an option to hyperref

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[unicode]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{Something like \texorpdfstring{$\boldsymbol{X_n^{\mathrm{red}}}$}{Xₙʳᵉᵈ}}
Lorem ipsum

\section{Or like \texorpdfstring{$\boldsymbol{V_k^{\mathrm{blue}}}$}{Vₖᵇˡᵘᵉ}}
dolor sit
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your use of `$\boldsymbol{...}$` is messing up `hyperref`'s ability to create somewhat-usable booktabs. I suggest you use `\boldmath $...$` instead. You'll still get warning messages of the type

```
Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (Unicode):
(hyperref)                removing `math shift' on input line 12.
```

but the booktab will say "Xnred", which is at least somewhat usable.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\bigskip
\hrule
\bigskip

\section{\boldmath Something like $X_n^{\mathrm{red}}$}

\end{document}
```